# what drains more my battery? wifi, dataconnection(3g) or gps. ANDROID

Tags: android, gps, android-wifi, power-management

I use the application profiler+ so i set some rules when to change profiles, but i am interested what drains more my android SE Arc S when the screen is off, is it if gps is turned on or WIFI ?

Comment: Empirically, GPS is worse than WiFi on my Asus EEE tablet, which doesn't have 3G, but I'm eager to see some hard facts come up here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My observations on my HTC Desire:

- Wifi: least amount of energy
- GPS needs more energy than Wifi
- 3G data connection needs even more energy.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to vary pretty wildly from model to model, but if you want empirical evidence, here's what I've found to affect my battery from greatest effect to least:

Devices: Galaxy Nexus, HTC Thunderbolt

- CPU Usage (even with screen off)
- 4G (LTE)
- WiFi (depending on what I'm doing)
- 3G
- Bluetooth

GPS doesn't even register for me in terms of battery drain.  WiFi is only bad if I'm out and about.  When I'm stable at work or home and there's a good strong signal WiFi isn't a big drain.